# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un correo desde el código C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando enviar un correo desde mi sistema al momento de crear un documento, pero me Envia el siguiente error:
'El servidor SMTP requiere una conexión segura o el cliente no se autenticó. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.57 '
He probado de diferentes metodos que he encontrado, pero todos me mandan el mismo error.

El codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente

```
  public static bool SendMail()
    {
        var resultado = false;
        string error = "";
        string claveCorreo = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminPassword"];
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("correoprueba@mail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("correoMio@correo.com", "Portal Empleados");
            mail.Subject = "Correo de Prueba";
            mail.Body = "Este es una prueba";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var smtp = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("correoMio@correo.com", claveCorreo),
                Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
            };
            smtp.Send(mail);
            resultado = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            error = e.Message.ToString();
            resultado = false;
        }
        return resultado;

    }
```

Comment: Office365 suele esperar STARTTLS sin SSL. Son cosas diferentes (hice un PR en un plugin de jenkins por eso mismo). No sé C# pero ese debe ser el lío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varios puntos

- TEMA 1: Recomendacion, utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0) es decir el componente [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/)
- TEMA 2: Enviar correo con MimeKit y seteando StartTls
- TEMA 3: Error al enviar por Outlook.com, requiere contraseña exlusiva de app

**TEMA 1:**

Primeramente **recomendacion**, tienes que utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0)
Puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) de donde podemos leer

> No se recomienda usar la SmtpClient clase para el nuevo desarrollo porque SmtpClient no admite muchos protocolos modernos. En su lugar, use MailKit u otras bibliotecas. Para obtener más información, consulte SmtpClient no se debe usar en GitHub.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**TEMA 2: Enviar correo con MimeKit y seteando StartTls**
Aqui tienes que utilizar el [componente nuget de MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) para utilizar la clase SmtpClient y enviar, pero antes debees conectarte... y enviar en dicha "conexion" el parametro de "options"  configurado con  [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Security_SecureSocketOptions.htm)
Ejemplo

- [gist - Send email with MimeKit + MailKit C# NET](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/a9697867882fc8a6199f5af6d6aabfd4)

Codigo

```
var from = new MailboxAddress(name: "Demo From", address: "...@outlook.com");
var to = new MailboxAddress(name: "Demo To", address: "...@gmail.com");


var msj = new MimeMessage();
msj.From.Add(from);
msj.To.Add(to);
msj.Subject = "Episode IV";
msj.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
{
    Text = "Starwars!"
};

var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();

client.Connect(host: "smtp.office365.com",
               port: 587,
               options: MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

//https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/account-billing/uso-de-contrase%C3%B1as-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-con-aplicaciones-que-no-admiten-la-verificaci%C3%B3n-en-dos-pasos-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944
client.Authenticate("....@outlook.com", "!#$%&");

client.Send(msj);

client.Disconnect(true);
```

**TEMA 3: Error al enviar por Outlook.com, requiere contraseña exclusiva de app**
Si con el codigo de arriba te conectas y da el siguiente error

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException
> Message=535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect.

Es porque tienes que habilitar una "contraseña de aplicacion". [Uso de contraseñas de la aplicación con aplicaciones que no admiten la verificación en dos pasos](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/account-billing/uso-de-contrase%C3%B1as-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-con-aplicaciones-que-no-admiten-la-verificaci%C3%B3n-en-dos-pasos-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944)
Es decir realizas la configuracion y outlook.com te brindara una contraseña para ser utilizada para conectarte (que no es la contraseña de tu casilla sino exlusiva para la aplicacion que estas desarrollando) esto es util cuando te quieres conectar con app clientes de envio

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/)
- [componente nuget de MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/)
- [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía