# ¿Alguna sintaxis para enviar correo electrónico en C#? ¿O pueden ver el error que tengo?

Tags: c#

Con un formulario de Windows Form estoy intentando enviar un correo electrónico, pero solo me marca error en el try, lo llegue a quitar, para ver el error mas especifico, pero solo me marco error en el servidor smtp. (en la linea de SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.lapaginaque.com");)
Agradecería mucho su ayuda si es que alguien nota el error o me pasa una nueva sintaxis... O de plano me recomiendan usar alguna otra librería para enviar correos.

```
using System.Net.Mail;


 private void ultraButton4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder MensBilder = new StringBuilder();
            MensBilder.Append(txtMensajeNE.Text.Trim() + " " + txtMensaje.Text.Trim());
            string xDe = txtDe.Text.Trim(); ;
            string xPara = txtParaNE.Text.Trim();
            string xAsunto = txtAsunto.Text.Trim();
            string xError = "";
            EnviarCorreo(MensBilder, DateTime.Now, xDe, xPara, xAsunto, out xError);
        }

        public static void EnviarCorreo(StringBuilder Mensaje, DateTime FechaEnvio, string De, string Para, string Asunto, out string Error)
        {

            Error = "";
            try
            {
                Mensaje.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                Mensaje.Append(string.Format("Este correo ha sido enviado el dia {0:dd/MM/yyyy} a las {0:HH:mm:ss} Hrs:  \n\n", FechaEnvio));
                Mensaje.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();
                Mail.From = new MailAddress(De);
                Mail.To.Add(Para);
                Mail.Subject = Asunto;
                Mail.Body = Mensaje.ToString();

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.lapaginaque.com");
                smtp.Port = 465;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Usuario, Password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Mail);
                Error = "Exito";
                MessageBox.Show(Error);
                
            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                Error = "Error: " + x.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(Error);
                return; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Y estas seguro que esa es la configuración correcta de tu smtp? Me refiero a si 465 es el port correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAs info en respuesta anterior

- [C# > ¿Como puedo enviar un correo desde el Código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562124/como-puedo-enviar-un-correo-desde-el-c%c3%b3digo/562338#562338)

Pero pego la primer parte aqui me parece relevante

- TEMA 1: Recomendacion, utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0) es decir el componente [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/)
- TEMA 2: Enviar correo con MimeKit y seteando StartTls

**TEMA 1:**

Primeramente **recomendacion**, tienes que utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0)
Puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) de donde podemos leer

> No se recomienda usar la SmtpClient clase para el nuevo desarrollo porque SmtpClient no admite muchos protocolos modernos. En su lugar, use MailKit u otras bibliotecas. Para obtener más información, consulte SmtpClient no se debe usar en GitHub.

**TEMA 2: Enviar correo con MimeKit y seteando StartTls**
Aqui tienes que utilizar el [componente nuget de MailKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/) para utilizar la clase SmtpClient y enviar, pero antes debees conectarte... y enviar en dicha "conexion" el parametro de "options"  configurado con  [MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_Security_SecureSocketOptions.htm)
Ejemplo

- [gist - Send email with MimeKit + MailKit C# NET](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/a9697867882fc8a6199f5af6d6aabfd4)

Codigo

```
var from = new MailboxAddress(name: "Demo From", address: "...@outlook.com");
var to = new MailboxAddress(name: "Demo To", address: "...@gmail.com");


var msj = new MimeMessage();
msj.From.Add(from);
msj.To.Add(to);
msj.Subject = "Episode IV";
msj.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
{
    Text = "Starwars!"
};

var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();

client.Connect(host: "smtp.office365.com",
               port: 587,
               options: MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

//https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/account-billing/uso-de-contrase%C3%B1as-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-con-aplicaciones-que-no-admiten-la-verificaci%C3%B3n-en-dos-pasos-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944
client.Authenticate("....@outlook.com", "!#$%&");

client.Send(msj);

client.Disconnect(true);
```

Importante!! Es la configuracion del servidor de correo que utilizas (que protocolo utiliza por default, etc) POr ejemplo hay servidores que por default es el
options: MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls

Por eso depende del tipo de servidor de correo que te conectes la configuracion.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.