# ¿Como colocar estilos o formato a un correo enviado desde net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy realizando una aplicación en net core mvc y estoy enviando una notificación por correo, pero se ve muy simple:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cuerpo de mi correo lo genero de la siguiente manera:

```
    public void EnviarCorreoTecnico(string correo, string empresa, string fechaCreacion)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(fromAddressServer);
        var toAddres = new MailAddress(correo);
        string fromPassword = passAddressServer;
        string subject = subjectHelpDesk;
        string body = $"Solicitante: {correo} ({empresa})" + "\n" + 
            $"Fecha de creación: {fechaCreacion}";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = host,
            Port = port,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddres)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        };

    }
```

Lo traté de hacer colocando las etiquetas de html dentro de mi `body` pero no resulto, espero me puedan apoyar con eso o decirme donde puedo investigar bien ya que no he encontrado documentación para ayudarme.

Comment: La libreria no te deja especificar que el cuerpo del correo es html?}

Comment: No lo se, es raro! coloco las etiquetas html dentro y cuando recibo el correo, se ve igual y se ven las etiquetas a los lados

Comment: No indicas la librería que estás usando para enviar correos. Asumiendo por tu código que es `System.Net.Mail` , debes de setear la propiedad `IsBodyHtml ` en true

Comment: Perdon, no entendí bien la respuesta pero si si es `System.Net.Mail`, Gracias javdromero

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/64615/822 Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias fredyfx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como te lo mencionó @javdromero en su comentario, debes configurar el mensaje para permitir código HTML y de esa manera dar estilo al correo.

Esto se hace con la propiedad `IsBodyHtml = true` (que por defecto es `false`) en el `MailMessage`, es decir esto:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddres)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true // <---- ESTO HAY QUE AGREGAR
})
```

---

Como nota personal, me gusta más el `using` de esta manera (sin los `{}`):

```
 using var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddres)
 {
     Subject = subject,
     Body = body,
     IsBodyHtml = true // <---- ESTO HAY QUE AGREGAR
 });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef.

Answer (score 1):

En un post anterior ya hablamos de este tema (te puede ser util) porque en una respuesta se encuentra

- [¿Por qué no se refleja mucho el diseño HTML en los correos cuando envió un correo desde C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/606210/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-refleja-mucho-el-dise%c3%b1o-html-en-los-correos-cuando-envi%c3%b3-un-corre/606218#606218)

Pero tambien (e incluso mas importante), veo que utilizas SmptClient

- [¿Cómo puedo enviar un correo desde el código C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/562124/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-enviar-un-correo-desde-el-c%c3%b3digo-c/562338#562338)

Primeramente **recomendacion**, tienes que utilizar [MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) en vez de [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0)
Puedes revisar la [documentación oficial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) de donde podemos leer

Siguiendo con el tema del estilo del email

Lo ideal que le des un estilo HTML (tags HTML con estilos CSS) al template que envias, para esto te puedes ayudar, y es la recomendacion, que utilices Frameworks CSS que tiene "exlusivos" template para los "mailing" Ejemplo Foundation for Emails

Es decir darle formato HTML (tienes que colocar que sea HTML) y por supuesto "armar la pagina que ira dentro"
Ejemplo

- [gist - Send email with MimeKit + MailKit C# NET](https://gist.github.com/fernandezja/a9697867882fc8a6199f5af6d6aabfd4)

Con respecto al framework CSS...

> Use Foundation for Emails to design responsive HTML emails that work
> in any email client.

- https://zurb.com/playground/responsive-email-templates
  https://get.foundation/emails.html
  https://get.foundation/emails/docs/

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose, ya estoy leyendo todo lo que me mandaste para mejorar el estilo de mi correo.